# How to prove this problem about approximated uniformly?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $D=\{z\in\Bbb C:a<|z|<b\}$ and, $f$ be a continuous function on
> boundary $∂D$. Show $f$ can be approximated uniformly on $∂D$ by
> polynomials in $z$ and $1/z$ iff  $f$ has a continuous extension to
> $D∪∂D$ that is analytic on $D$.

**Necessity：** Let $P_n$ be a sequence of polynomial approximating $f$. Write $|P_n(z)-P_m(z)|＜ε$ for  $z∈∂D$. We know Inequality is true for $z∈∂D$ by maximal module principle. Then we can see necessity is ture.

**Sufficient  condition:** Let $P_n(z)$ be Summation of Laurent series. We only need to  prove $f(z)$ can be approximated uniformly on $\{|z|=b\}$ and $\{|z|=a\}$.
Consider $f(rz)$  $ r∈[t,1)  z∈{|z|=b} $such that $rz∈D$. Write$ |f(z) -Pn(z)|≤|f(z)-f(rz)|+
|f(rz)-P_n(rz)|+|P_n(z)-P_n(rz)|$.
I can estimate the first two items by continuous uniformly on$D∪∂D$ and converges uniformly on compact subset.We can find$ N$ from converges uniformly and sufficient large r tend to 1. I want to sue continuous uniformly for The third item but i can't sure the r can make Inequality $|P_n(z)-P_n(rz)|＜ε/3 $for every$ n ≥N$.

Comment: You have asked a total of $7$ questions already. This is time to know mathjax for writing math notation. You can learn it from here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference very easily. **I have left some portion so that you can try on it.**

Comment: Also. what is your question? **Do you need verification of your solution?** There is a solution-verification tag.

Comment: I can't estimate  the third Inequality.

Comment: The fomula is beautiful by use mathjax! I want to use it to write fomula.But i don't know use it by Mobile phone,and i try to find and  download it but i haven't find.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out to be used like this!